# Is there a shortcut to open the 3D view?

Tags: 3d-view, shortcut

Is there a shortcut to go to 3D view when you are in another view, such the UV/Image editor or the Node Editor?

I can't find it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> - <kbd>F12</kbd> keys

<kbd>F5</kbd> for 3D view.

---

<kbd>F3</kbd> = Node Editor

<kbd>F4</kbd> = Console

<kbd>F5</kbd> = 3D View

<kbd>F6</kbd> = Curve editor

<kbd>F7</kbd> = Properties

<kbd>F8</kbd> = VSE

<kbd>F9</kbd> = Outliner

<kbd>F10</kbd> = Image/Uv editor

<kbd>F11</kbd> = Text Editor

<kbd>F12</kbd> = Dopesheet editor

Don't know where timeline went.